# java add item from a arraylist to another arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

see if someone can answer this question. 
I have an arraylist that contains elements. I want his id or position put it in another  arraylist.Se as copying a arraylist in another:

```
al_strings1.addAll (al_strings2);
```

but I want to enter only the item in position 3, for example. how can I do that?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it from one, put it in another

```
al_strings1.add(al_strings2.get(fromPosition));
```

the same as doing

```
Object itemFromListTwo = al_strings2.get(fromPosition);
al_strings1.add(itemFromListTwo);
```

Comment: Thank you very much to all for the replies. Can you tell me?  because are  my question in the negative? What have I done wrong? I'm New Here, if you said that I've done wrong, I will learn. Is it because of my low level of English?

Comment: People tend to down vote if it's something that can be found out by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Object> newList = new ArrayList<Object>(oldList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use something as simple as:

```
al_strings1.add(al_strings2.get(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply add the item :

```
al_strings1.add(al_strings2.get(3));
```

to replace it :

```
al_strings1.set(3, al_strings2.get(3));
```